# separating Akka actors from implementation logic

Tags: design-patterns, akka, actor

Is there a design pattern that would be commonly applied to facilitate the separation of concerns between an Akka actor's message handling and the business logic that it implements?

Comment: Take a look at this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37055472/scala-akka-discrete-event-simulation/37073030#37073030

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not specific to Akka but I think one reasonable approach is to put the logic into traits a la the "cake" pattern:

`http://www.cakesolutions.net/teamblogs/2011/12/19/cake-pattern-in-depth`

Though it's more broadly a pattern for doing dependency injection, you can apply with actors as well.  Your trait can contain re-usable functions you can mix in and Using the self-type annotation in your trait can theoretically allow your business logic code to access actor state (only if absolutely necessary).